# iTunes on Windows 7: Which fonts are they using?

Tags: windows-7, itunes, fonts

Looking at iTunes today, I've come to a conclusion that the fonts are really nice.

I have English, Chinese, Japanese and Korean songs and they do look really good together. Just wondering if it's one font or many fonts used? And of course what font is it?

EDIT: A possible match would be Segoe UI for English and Meiryo UI for Japanese. That's all I can find for now.

Comment: Added `Segoe UI` and `Meiryo UI` after some searching.

Answer (score 2):

Their site is using a font that matches the one used in iTunes, and the base.css of their site has the following code:

```
body { font: 12px/18px "Lucida Grande", "Lucida Sans Unicode", Helvetica, Arial, Verdana, sans-serif; background-color: #fff; color: #333; }*/
```

So it has to be the first or the second option if Lucida grande is not installed in your system.

Search C://Windows/Fonts for **Lucida Grande** or **Lucida Sans**